# Multiple Bean Configurations of a Class

Tags: java, spring

I have 2 beans configured for a class so that I can configure the class with two different data layer implementations. What I'm wondering is if there is a pattern or best practice for selecting between the two different beans in my code.  I know without Spring, the Factory pattern would be commonly used for this, but it seems a bit redundant being as beans are retrieved from Spring via a factory.

Comment: No, I am using XML configuration. I am learning Spring on my own. Basically, I am injecting 2 different data storage services into my bean, one for storing via JDBC and one for storing via XML. The user can select which storage method they want to use and I am looking for the easiest way to retrieve the correct bean based on the customer choice without having multiple if/else blocks in various parts of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem having a Factory within a Factory. It happens all the time in Spring, in fact. I'd say that sounds like a good approach here. Your data storage factory would be a Spring bean and be injected with the two different implementations, which are also beans. The job of the factory is to choose between them based on some input.

Answer (score 0):

Declare both beans and mark one as *primary*. You can either use:

```
<bean primary="true" ...
```

in XML configuration or:

```
@Primary
@Bean
```

In `@Configuration` approach. Spring will prefer primary beans when performing autowiring. [Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) documentation.